# mypy not recognizing value in class function that could potentially be None and cause an error

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a class that looks as following:

```
from typing import Optional, Tuple
import numpy as np

class TestClass():

    def __init__(self, a: Optional[float] = None):
        self.a = np.radians(a) if a is not None else None

    def test(self) -> None:
        b = np.cos(self.a)
```

In the case of `a` being None, test() results in an error raised by numpy when run normally. However, mypy doesn't recognize the possibility of self.a being None here even though it is explicitly defined in **init**. Mypy raises the expected error `Argument 1 to "__call__" of "ufunc" has incompatible type "Optional[float]"; expected "Union[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic], Sequence[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic]], Sequence[Sequence[Any]], _SupportsArray]"` if the expression in test() is changed to `b = np.cos(None)`. How do I get mypy to recognize this type problem?

Comment: What version of python are you using cause I'm unable to reproduce the error, I'm getting no issues on python 3.8.5

Comment: @darthbaba I am also using 3.8.5, but the point is that the posted snippet does not cause an error even though self.a could be a None type. If you replace the self.a in test() with None you get the expected error.